# NullPointerException when query contact information

Tags: java, android

I'm querying the contact information to get the phone number and email address,
here is my code:

```
protected void onPreExecute() {
    // get total count
    Cursor count = getContentResolver().query(
    ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    total = count.getCount();

    // setup progress dialog
    progressDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.profile_synchonizing));
    progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    progressDialog.setProgress(0);
    progressDialog.setMax(total);
    progressDialog.show();        // Profile.java:270
}

protected Void doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
        String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

        if (Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
            Cursor phoneNumber = getContentResolver().query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[] { contactId }, null);
            while (phoneNumber.moveToNext()) {
                // do something
            }
        }

        Cursor emails = getContentResolver().query(Email.CONTENT_URI, null, Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[] { contactId }, null);
        while (emails.moveToNext()) {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

I have made sure that the contact has phone number,
however I still got null pointer exception in these line:

```
while (phoneNumber.moveToNext())     //Profile.java:315
while (emails.moveToNext())
```

Exception stack:

```
08-15 16:41:33.162: E/AndroidRuntime(20283): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
08-15 16:41:33.162: E/AndroidRuntime(20283): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
08-15 16:41:33.162: E/AndroidRuntime(20283):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
08-15 16:41:33.162: E/AndroidRuntime(20283):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
08-15 16:41:33.162: E/AndroidRuntime(20283):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
08-15 16:41:33.162: E/AndroidRuntime(20283):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
08-15 16:41:33.162: E/AndroidRuntime(20283):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
08-15 16:41:33.162: E/AndroidRuntime(20283):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
08-15 16:41:33.162: E/AndroidRuntime(20283):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
08-15 16:41:33.162: E/AndroidRuntime(20283):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1027)
08-15 16:41:33.162: E/AndroidRuntime(20283): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-15 16:41:33.162: E/AndroidRuntime(20283):    at test.Profile$SyncContactAsync.doInBackground(Profile.java:315)
08-15 16:41:33.162: E/AndroidRuntime(20283):    at test.Profile$SyncContactAsync.doInBackground(Profile.java:1)
08-15 16:41:33.162: E/AndroidRuntime(20283):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
08-15 16:41:33.162: E/AndroidRuntime(20283):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
08-15 16:41:33.162: E/AndroidRuntime(20283):    ... 4 more
08-15 16:41:33.902: D/WindowManagerImpl(20283): finishRemoveViewLocked, mViews[0]: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40545090
08-15 16:41:33.932: E/WindowManager(20283): Activity test.TabScreen has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@405bc868 that was originally added here
08-15 16:41:33.932: E/WindowManager(20283): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity test.TabScreen has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@405bc868 that was originally added here
08-15 16:41:33.932: E/WindowManager(20283):     at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:278)
08-15 16:41:33.932: E/WindowManager(20283):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:149)
08-15 16:41:33.932: E/WindowManager(20283):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
08-15 16:41:33.932: E/WindowManager(20283):     at     android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:433)
08-15 16:41:33.932: E/WindowManager(20283):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:265)
08-15 16:41:33.932: E/WindowManager(20283):     at test.Profile$SyncContactAsync.onPreExecute(Profile.java:270)
08-15 16:41:33.932: E/WindowManager(20283):     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:391)
08-15 16:41:33.932: E/WindowManager(20283):     at test.Profile$3.onItemClick(Profile.java:235)
08-15 16:41:33.932: E/WindowManager(20283):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
08-15 16:41:33.932: E/WindowManager(20283):     at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3569)
08-15 16:41:33.932: E/WindowManager(20283):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1831)
08-15 16:41:33.932: E/WindowManager(20283):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-15 16:41:33.932: E/WindowManager(20283):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-15 16:41:33.932: E/WindowManager(20283):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
08-15 16:41:33.932: E/WindowManager(20283):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4385)
08-15 16:41:33.932: E/WindowManager(20283):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-15 16:41:33.932: E/WindowManager(20283):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-15 16:41:33.932: E/WindowManager(20283):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
08-15 16:41:33.932: E/WindowManager(20283):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
08-15 16:41:33.932: E/WindowManager(20283):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I checked the contact that threw the exception, it has phone number and email address.
What's wrong with my code?

Comment: post the exception call stack

Comment: phoneNumber throw null pointer exception, if skip it then emails throw exception, too.

Comment: can you post onPreExecute of the SyncContactAsync class

Comment: maybe you are using getApplicationContext to initialize progressdialog? If so change it Activity.this. Do check this once

Comment: I use `Profile.this` to initialize the progressdialog.
I found that all the contact throw exception are not local phone contact, but facebook, skype contact...etc, I thought that's the problem maybe?

Comment: you are using Profile.this but the activity name seems to be test.TabScreen . Use Tabscreen.this instead of Profile.this.

Comment: I found the problem......I didn't close the cursor!!
Just close phoneNumber and email after each iteration,
then everything works......
I am an idiot LOL

Answer (score 2):

You should call `moveToFirst()` on all the cursors before traversing their data e.g.

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver.query( ... );
cursor.moveToFirst();
while( cursor.moveToNext() ) {
    // process data here...
}
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: I added `moveToFirst()` to cursor, phoneNumber, and emails in my code, but exceptions occur still......

Answer (score 0):

You possibly forgot the contacts read-permission in your manifest (AndroidManifest.xml):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

Note: This also causes NULL-pointer exceptions.

Comment: Maybe your doInBackground()-Functions Code needs to be within the UI thread. Try to put your contacts-access code into the UI Thread for a test. If it's working there, thats possibly the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you check your cursor for null value BEFORE you use it?
Then, you can check your queries why they return no results

Comment: I checked, I just don't know why they are null,
until I found that I didn't close them in last iteration......

Comment: Your code does **NOT** check the cursor before executing `moveToNext()`.
Now, check **generated SQL and parameters**.

Just a wild guess here: examples seem to use no spaces in generated SQL - try Phone.CONTACT_ID + "=?"

Comment: I mean I checked it before, and not on the code pasted here.
And I found the problem is I didn't close the cursor now.

Comment: It seems the too many unclosed cursor make system cannot make new querying, so it return null...LOL